# what packages to install for node.js

Tags: node.js, package

I just installed node.js and I was wondering what are some common packages to install to get me rolling.

What are some popular packages and their functions?

Comment: What are you trying to do with node?

Comment: "I'm going to start programming. What are popular keys on the keyboard I need to learn?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`express` as an http server, and `request` as an http client are the most common libraries used almost everywhere as far as I know

but yes, it depends on what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0):

https://npmjs.org/

here you will find all you need for any solution,
HOW TO, installation, APIs, etc.